# Samba Server Folder Access not Permitted

Tags: networking, server, permissions, samba, backup

I can't seem to get windows to connect to the samba file server (error below). I'm using \ \ip\backup where ip is replaced with the internal ip address. It registers the correct folder but comes back with a permission error. I thought I made it so it should be a public share (no login required). What have I done wrong? Did I add a parameter I didn't need to that's causing the error? Or is there another parameter I need to add? Some info below.

Client side: Windows 10
Server side: Ubuntu server 20.04LTS

[image: Windows error]

Config file block

```
[backup]
  path = /media/raid/backup-desktop
  browsable =yes
  writable = yes
  guest ok = yes
  read only = no
  public = yes
```

testparm output:

```
$ testparm
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
Loaded services file OK.
Weak crypto is allowed
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions

# Global parameters
[global]
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        logging = file
        map to guest = Bad User
        max log size = 1000
        obey pam restrictions = Yes
        pam password change = Yes
        panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
        passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
        passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
        server role = standalone server
        server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
        unix password sync = Yes
        usershare allow guests = Yes
        idmap config * : backend = tdb


[printers]
        browseable = No
        comment = All Printers
        create mask = 0700
        path = /var/spool/samba
        printable = Yes


[print$]
        comment = Printer Drivers
        path = /var/lib/samba/printers


[backup]
        guest ok = Yes
        path = /media/raid/backup-desktop
        read only = No
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not just a permissions error, but a very specific permissions error.

The smb protocol does not support multiple credentials on the same connection from a client.  You have another share from the same server on the local client that is using different credentials than the one you just tried to make.

Your options to resolve this are:

- Determine what the first share is, and connect to the second one using the same credentials
- Follow the directions in the error, and disconnect the first share before attempting to connect the second share with the supplied (or default) credentials
- If you really must connect a client to multiple shares on a server under different credentials, sometimes you can get away with pretending it is multiple servers by connecting to different hostnames for the same server.  This option is not always available, and doesn't always work.

Comment: The only other thing that’s running is a Nextcloud server. I don’t have any other samba share folders.

Comment: It's not how many shares there are that matters.  It matters how many times you have tried to connect to them on the client side.

Comment: Got it. But the question on how I can make this accessible without login credentials remains. Not sure what I'm doing wrong on that end.

Comment: Either connect all shares without login credentials or all shares with the same credentials.  It is getting harder and harder to even offer shares without credentials these days.